# Reading datasets for geopandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, geopandas

I trying reads data for dataset with help of geopandas, but interpreter wright:

> File
>   "/home/divinitytoffee/PycharmProjects/Radar/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/geopandas/datasets/**init**.py",
>   line 33, in get_path raise alueError(msg) ValueError: The dataset
>   'resource/RAVL_vLuki/rd0a0h.00d' is not available

```
import geopandas as gpd
import fiona.ogrext
import pandas as pd

gpd_data = gpd.gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('resource/RAVL_vLuki/rd0a0h.00d'))
```

Actually the question, how to fix?
Data are presented in the form of a `*.00d`

Comment: could you please `import os` and add the output of `os.listdir('resource')` and if `RAVL_vLuki` is in that, the output of `os.listdir('resource/RAVL_vLuki')`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: @NicoAlbers ['RAVO_Vojeikovo', 'RUDP_petrozavodsk', 'RAVL_vLuki'](recource)
['rdsrse.00d', 'rdhj88.00d', 'rd3bmy.00d', 'rdop1a.00d', 'rdtgvn.00d',..]('RVAL_vLuki')

Answer (score 1):

The `geopandas.datasets.get_path` is meant to return the path of a few datasets that are *included* in the geopandas library itself (eg for examples).

When reading your own file, you need to pass the path directly to `read_file`:

```
gpd_data = gpd.gpd.read_file('resource/RAVL_vLuki/rd0a0h.00d')
```

Comment: It didn't help. By the way, pandas.read_fwf('resource/RAVL_vLuki/rd0a0h.00d'), read this file, but щгеput with bad encoding.

Comment: Maybe because 'resource/RAVL_vLuki/rd0a0h.00d' is actually not a geospatial file format?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to import it as a data frame?

I don't know if this will help.

```py
import geopandas as gpd
gpd_data = gpd.gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file('resource/RAVL_vLuki/rd0a0h.00d')
```